# When are timeouts deleted by the browser?

Tags: javascript

When you set a timeout with Javascript using:

```js
const id = window.setTimeout(func, ms);
```

What events could lead it to be cleared before being executed?

The timeout can be cleared manually using `window.clearTimeout(id)`, but what else could also clear it?

Does navigating within the same site clear it?
Or does navigating to a different site clear it?

Answer (score 1):

The timers will be cancelled when:

- You cancel them (`clearTimeout`, `clearInterval`, etc.).
- If the page is torn down.

So:

> Does navigating within the same site clear it?

Yes, if by "navigating" you mean following a `<a href="foo">` or similar in the usual way, assigning to `location`, etc. If you "navigate" by just changing the DOM (as in a single-page applicatio), that doesn't tear down the page so it doesn't cancel timers, but normal navigation does.